# In Selenium, does the waitForPageToLoad command have a Target value?

Tags: selenium

Perhaps I'm a bit confused about when to use the `waitForPageToLoad` command, but what would I put into the Target  box? So far, I have:

Command: waitForPageToLoad

Target:

Value:   7000

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Selenium IDE for Firefox, what you have should be sufficient. The [docs](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.ISelenium.WaitForPageToLoad.html) only specify the timeout when waiting for the navigated-to page to load.